# SQL group by clause with two columns

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql, view

Have a TSQL view, which I need to group by one column, however, am using nhibernate(C#) and am required to specify the Id column too.. my query looks like:

```
SELECT
    row_number() over(order by id)as Id,
        column_name,..etc
from tblName
group by column_name
```

which gives me an error that the Id has to be included in the group by clause.

Alternatively, I can write:

```
SELECT
    row_number() over(order by id)as Id,
        column_name,..etc
from tblName
group by column_name, id
```

which return multiple rows of the same column_name name.

Is there a way around this?

Comment: when using `GROUP BY` especially on `T-SQL`, you must aggregate some of your columns. It is easy to understand the problem if you can give sample records with desired result.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think you want to do this:

```
  Select row_number() over(order by column_name) as ID, column_name from (
      Select distinct column_name from tblName
   ) as A
```

Answer (score 0):

Do you mean this?

```
SELECT
    row_number() over(partition by column_name order by id)as Id,
        column_name,..etc
from tblName
```